# What is the problem with my point in polygon function?

Tags: c++, math

I'm trying to make lasso feature like in Photoshop or other similar image-editing programs.

[I have a point in polygon function which checks for every pixel in image if it lies within custom-made polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0zUm.png)

[Then I color every non-matching pixel transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn6bb.png)

However these lines occur and the function says that those pixels lie within given polygon.

Point in polygon function:

```
#define INF 10000 
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
bool onSegment(Point p, Point q, Point r)
{
    if (q.x <= max(p.x, r.x) && q.x >= min(p.x, r.x) &&
        q.y <= max(p.y, r.y) && q.y >= min(p.y, r.y))
        return true;
    return false;
}
int orientation(Point p, Point q, Point r)
{
    int val = (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) -
        (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y);

    if (val == 0) return 0; 
    return (val > 0) ? 1 : 2; 
}

bool doIntersect(Point p1, Point q1, Point p2, Point q2)
{

    int o1 = orientation(p1, q1, p2);
    int o2 = orientation(p1, q1, q2);
    int o3 = orientation(p2, q2, p1);
    int o4 = orientation(p2, q2, q1);

    if (o1 != o2 && o3 != o4)
        return true;


    if (o1 == 0 && onSegment(p1, p2, q1)) return true;


    if (o2 == 0 && onSegment(p1, q2, q1)) return true;


    if (o3 == 0 && onSegment(p2, p1, q2)) return true;

    if (o4 == 0 && onSegment(p2, q1, q2)) return true;

    return false;
}


bool isInside(vector<Point> polygon, Point p)
{
    int n = polygon.size();

    if (n < 3) return false;


    Point extreme = { INF, p.y };


    int count = 0, i = 0;
    do
    {
        int next = (i + 1) % n;


        if (doIntersect(polygon[i], polygon[next], p, extreme))
        {
        
            if (orientation(polygon[i], p, polygon[next]) == 0)
                return onSegment(polygon[i], p, polygon[next]);

            count++;
        }
        i = next;
    } while (i != 0);


    return count & 1; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to break if one of the affected pixels is being processed? With GDB you could use `(gdb) break polygon.cpp:<line number you want to stop at> if p == {<x coordinate>, <y coordinate>}`.

Comment: Just tested and every pixel of the image is being processed, the problem is with polygon collision function.

Comment: What is the problem with polygon collision function? Did you try to debug the function?

Comment: It finds those lines of pixels to lie within the polygon, while they're not there. I'm asking for how can I fix the function.

Comment: Start your program in a debugger, e.g. GDB. Set a conditional breakpoint in `isInside` for a point that is falsely classified. Step line by line through the function and check the variables and return values to find the problem in that funciton.

Comment: These lines only occour on rows with a corner. Probably the count is wrong on this rows. `if (doIntersect(polygon[i], polygon[next], p, extreme))` can be true twice if it's a corner, first for `doIntersect(polygon[i], polygon[next], p, extreme)` and then for `doIntersect(polygon[next], polygon[(next + 1) % n], p, extreme)`.